# Error when saving data to MSSQL file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Thanks to some help I fixed some of my previous problems but when i click the register button(`button1`) I get the following error:

`ERROR = ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;


public partial class CompanyLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = @".\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VCtemps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

    string sql = "insert into company values(@CompName, @BusinessType, @Pword)";
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql);
    string CompName = txtCompName.Text;
    string BusinessType = DropDownList1.Text;
    string Pword = txtPassword.Text;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into company(CompName, BusinessType, Pword) Values(@CompName,@BusinessType,@Pword);";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompName",SqlDbType.VarChar);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BusinessType",SqlDbType.VarChar);    
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pword",SqlDbType.VarChar);    

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();

    txtCompName.Text = "";
    txtPassword.Text = "";
    DropDownList1.Text = "";
}
}
```

Comment: note that you're setting the SQL text twice. You should remove one of them (the first one - which is incorrect) to avoid confusion.

Comment: ..and also, all of your AddWithValue lines are incorrect. You've passed in an SqlDbType rahter than the actual value. You should be passing the value to this function. 

eg: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompName", CompName);

Answer (score 2):

pretty self explanatory error message. you need to specify a data source and a driver in your connection string. visit [Connection Strings for Database](http://www.connectionstrings.com) to find what a connection string should look like for the database you're targeting.

Comment: Apart from the issue I raised with the double-escaping it exactly matches the connection string for SQLEXPRESS on the site you linked to, which is: 

Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=Yes;

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string, you've escaped your blackslashes AND you've used the @ sign in front of the string. Possibly the problem is that you've done both. Either remove the @ or remove the double slashes in both places.

```
@".\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\VCtemps.mdf...etc
```

...but to be honest, you shouldn't hard-code your connection string like that anyway. You should add your connection string to the web.config file to the ConnectionStrings section:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
       <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString=".\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\VCtemps.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
...
```

Then change your code to:

```
conn.ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```